# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_URL Maximum Length?

Tags: php

I have this code to validate whether a URL inputted is valid...

```
if(filter_var($param1, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE){
    echo "invalidURL";
    exit();
}
```

But when testing with this long-yet-valid url it says it's invalid...

http://www.thisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislongthisurlislong.com

Anyone have any ideas why?  I can't find anything in FILTER_VALIDATE_URL that says it should consider a url of this length to be invalid, but simply by deleting characters it will eventually be deemed valid.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, just found this after a little more research...

"According to [RFC 1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt), each part of domain name label cannot exceed 63 characters."

(source: http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-git-pulls/149gqytbpr/pr-php-src-826-master-filter-validate-url-check-max-length-of-domain-name-label).

So it wasn't a valid URL after all - well done php!